# compile ECL in Windows error

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, common-lisp, ecl

ecl-13.5.1, windows xp

I go into "msvc" dir then use nmake and some options.

Then I cannot get ecl.dll but a memory error!
ecl_min.exe cause the error.

The version of msvc is vs2008.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I only ever built ECL on Linux, so I don't know what the problem may be, but, for certain, you will get better feedback if you post the text of compiler error, tag this question with msvc tag and maybe find the corresponding code in ECL that the compiler didn't like. Also, it is important to state the VC version. Also, I'd try Mingw or GCC via Cygwin. I'd imagine them to be better tested.

Comment: There is no compile error and ecl_min.exe is created, but when run ecl_min.exe causes a error.And I'll try GCC in Mingw. Another is in ecl's homepage, I cannot find a download file with bianary file in windows. Thank you for your response.

Comment: To my best knowledge ECL is distributed as source code. So there might not be a precompiled binary distribution. Visual Studio 2008 is two major versions behind the current one and Microsoft compilers haven't been known for implementing standards, so who knows... And, if you are more familiar with MS compilers, well, then maybe start ECL from debugger and see where it breaks? I'm fairly certain its makefile has a key for compiling it with debugging information. That way you'd have a more concrete error.

Comment: I just try Mingw, I use this way. I goto dir the ./configure, then make all, After this, I get same error, ecl_min.exe fail. I use msvs just because I have, and I tried nmake DEBUG_XXX = 1 and get some unicode options, but all I get same error.. Help me!

Comment: Well... unless you tell what the error is it's hard to tell. Also, I really never compiled it on Windows and hadn't had problems with it on Linux. I'd suggest you ask on the mailing list: http://sourceforge.net/p/ecls/mailman/?source=navbar . I had a quick scan through the questions asked on the list. http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=87li3mqm7p.fsf%40sandalphon.casenave-pere.fr&forum_name=ecls-list this thread could be potentially your problem, so, perhaps, if the poster solved it, might be worthwhile to ask him.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm trying to compile new source code.